# Having issue with Battery status in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, ionic4

I'm using Ionic4 and I'm trying to get the device battery level. But I get an error:
 ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target
and for the battery level, I get undefined.

Has anyone run into the same problem

Comment: Here is my ionic info https://pastebin.com/TZ8qxx8n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to get the battery status in Ionic 4:

```
window.addEventListener('batterystatus', this.onBatteryStatus, false);

onBatteryStatus(status) {
console.log('Level: ' + status.level + ' isPlugged: ' + status.isPlugged);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug report at ionic: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2972

Unfortunately no solution yet, however there is a workaround to bypass the ionic typescript wrapper and just listen directly on the window events.

```
fromEvent(window, 'batterystatus').subscribe((status) => {
    console.log(status)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way could be like this:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/battery-status@4
```

Then in your code:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BatteryStatus } from '@ionic-native/battery-status';

batterylevel = 0;


constructor(...
           private batteryStatus: BatteryStatus,
           private plt: Platform ) {}

ionViewDidEnter() 
{     
  // Cordova check
  if(this.plt.is('core') || this.plt.is('mobileweb')) 
  {
   // NO. It's a browser.
   // don't call the batery.   
  }
  else
  { 

    const batterysubscription = this.batteryStatus.onChange().subscribe(status => {  
  this.batterylevel = status.level;
     });
   } 

}

yourfunction()
{
  console.log(this.batterylevel);
}
```

You'll also need to add it to your provider list too.

Of course, this will only work in emulation or a device.